# adjust WSL for changed windows user folder

Tags: windows, ubuntu, windows-subsystem-for-linux

I recently changed the name of my windows user folder, eg. C:/Users/Userx --> C:/Users/User1, which led to loosing my previous setup of WSL. upon opening WSL acted as if it was never opened before and installed ubuntu and asked for a new username etc.

what do I need to change to get my old setup (home directory, installed software, shell settings, etc.) back?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I got an answer over at Reddit:
https://www.reddit.com/r/bashonubuntuonwindows/comments/m9evxo/wsl_setup_gone_after_changing_name_of_windows/

Apperently, in this special case, WSL Ubuntu overwrites the old installation with a new one and you have to set everything up again. Data and settings are gone after the new installation. One answer stated that if I hadn't opened WSL after changing the name of the Win10 user folder, the data could have been salvaged.